# Interpretation of a combinatorial expression

Tags: combinatorics

I came across this expression :

$ \frac {(2n)!} {2^n n!} $

I know that this evaluates to an odd integer. More specifically :

$ \frac {(2n)!} {2^n n!} = (2n -1) \cdot (2n - 3)\cdots 5\cdot3\cdot1$

I want to know where this expression comes in a real-life scenario. For example $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}$ represents the number of ways to choose a subset from a set of cardinality $n$.

Comment: For interpretations see [OEIS sequence A001147](https://oeis.org/A001147). Double factorial of odd numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(2n-1)!!=(2n-1)\cdot(2n-3)\cdot(2n-5)\cdots 5\cdot 3\cdot 1$ is an answer to various combinatorial questions such as the following:

> In how many ways can $2n$ distinct people split up into $n$ *unlabelled* teams each of size two such that everyone is on exactly one team each.

To see the answer, place an arbitrary order on the $2n$ people.  Without loss of generality, let the order we use be age.

Take whoever is youngest in the group.  Pick who will be partnered with the youngest person.  Remove both people from the pool of available people.

Take whoever is youngest from those remaining.  Pick who will be partnered with that person.  Remove both people from the pool of available people.

Repeat the previous step until everyone is paired off.

Comment: Two questions: 1. Why impose an order on the list of 2n items? 2. Why pick only the first entry of the remaining ordered list as one of the members of the team?

Comment: Why impose an order? Because you always may.  Why always pick the first remaining?  To avoid double counting.  To rephrase the question, it asks in how many ways we can form an unordered partition of a set with 2n elements into parts all of size two, remembering that the order within the parts as well as the order of the parts themselves are irrelevant.

Comment: In an alternate explanation of the calculation you can temporarily assume teams were labeled and then divide by $n!$, the number of times you counted each scenario.  I prefer avoiding division by symmetry arguments whenever possible.